# Differential Drive Robot with Trailer - Challenges in Integrating Physical Constraints with nav2 Planners

Tags: ros2, ros-iron

I am currently working on a project involving a differential drive robot towing a trailer, and I am using nav2 (ROS2) for navigation. However, I'm currently facing a challenge as the available planners do not account for the physical constraints of such a robot, specifically:

- dynamic and non-circular shape (base + trailer) to avoid collisions with obstacles,
- limited turning radius dependent on the current position of the trailer.

Until now, I managed to generate paths with the Smac Hybrid A* Planner, using increased inflation radius on obstacles, and minimal turning radius corresponding to the "worst case" where the trailer angle is maximum. This is not optimal as the robot must drive further from obstacles, and cannot rotate in place.

I have explored the documentation and options, but it seems that the currently available planners are not designed to handle non-circular / non-holonomic robots. I start considering to add a custom cost function within the planner to account for its physical constraints.

If anyone in the community has experience with a similar setup or can suggest modifications, plugins, or alternative planners within nav2 that might better suit a differential drive robot towing a trailer, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Thank you for your time and assistance!

Comment: The Smac Planners are specifically designed for non-circular, non-holonomic robots. They are simply not designed for trailer situations - I recommend looking into articulated minimum control sets for the State Lattice planner.